# How can I make scipy.odeint to be faster?

Tags: optimization, scipy, odeint

I am currently solving an integrated system of 559 non linear differential equations.I have to fit the solutions obtained to some experimental data by varying the constants c1,c2 b and g.
I am using scipy.odeint and I would like to know if there is a way to make my program faster as it takes ages to run.

The code is this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import random as rd
from numba import jit

L=np.loadtxt('C:/Users/Pablo/Desktop/TFG/Probas/matriz_L_Pablo.txt')  
I=np.loadtxt('C:/Users/Pablo/Desktop/TFG/Probas/vector_I_Pablo.txt')



k=np.diag(L)
n=len(k)  #Contamos o numero de nodos

u=np.zeros(n)
for i in range (n):
    u[i]=rd.random()


M=np.zeros((n,n))
derivs=np.zeros(n)

c1=100 ; c2=10000 ; b=0.01 ; g=1


@jit
def f(y,t,params):
    suma=0
    c1,c2,b,g=params
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i==j:
                M[i,i]=(1-y[i]/b)+g*(1-y[i])+c2*I[i]*(1/n-1)
            if i!=j:
                M[i,j]=(1/n)*(c1*L[i,j]+c2*I[i])
            out=(M[i,j]*y[j])
            suma=suma+out
        derivs[i]=suma
        suma=0
    return derivs





#Condicions iniciais

y0=u

#lista cos parametros
params=[c1,c2,b,g]

#tempos de int
tf=1
deltat=0.001
t=np.arange(0,tf,deltat)

#solucion

sol= odeint(f, y0,t, args=(params,))
```

(Sorry if it is not very clear it's my first time here)

Answer (score 0):

You can try vectorizing your code. The function f does 2 things - first it creates the matrix M, and then does the multiplication $$M*y$$. The multiplication $$M*y$$ is easy to vectorize because all we have to do is use numpy's matmul function.

```
def f(y,t,params):
    suma=0
    c1,c2,b,g=params
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i==j:
                M[i,i]=(1-y[i]/b)+g*(1-y[i])+c2*I[i]*(1/n-1)
            if i!=j:
                M[i,j]=(1/n)*(c1*L[i,j]+c2*I[i])

    return np.matmul(M,y)
```

That should help with runtime a bit. But the most time consuming part is the fact that the entire matrix M is formed every time f is called, and that it is formed one element at a time. 
The only parts of M that need to be modified when calling f, are the parts which depend on y. So all of the off diagonal entries in M can be filled before the ode solver is called. So if M is (569x569), instead of having to calculate all ~250000+ elements of M every time f is called, you would only have to calculate the 569 elements of M on the diagonal. The remaining 250000 entries of M don't depend on y, and are specified before calling the ode solver. Making this modification should result in a huge speedup as this seems to be the main bottleneck in your code. 
Lastly, you could also vectorize how the diagonal of M is filled by using something like numpy.diag_indices.